# Pagination: How can I handle an error if the parameter is not passed in get request in php?

Tags: php, pagination

```
$pagenum=$_GET['pagenum'];
```

I have written a code for pagination in a single file. When I open the first time that page, it gives me an error. I think it is because parameter `pagenum` is not passed in *GET* request. How can i handle this?

Otherwise the code is running perfectly. But the issue is to handle that error when opening the page for the first time...

Comment: When asking for help, state what you expect to happen and what actually happens, which includes any error messages. In short, include exact error messages in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you could write it something like this, to where if there is no page number specified it defaults to 1

```
$pagenum=isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? intval($_GET['pagenum']) : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP pages shouldn't break by not receiving a parameter.  I'd check elsewhere.  What error are you getting?

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: pagenum in C:\wamp\www\AR\tempjsnoget.php on line 11
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0048 382704 {main}( ) ..\tempjsnoget.php:0
1DAIICTCEP Daiict23.18852700000000000072.628147000000000000
2DAIICTLab daiict23.18711200000000000072.628324000000000000
3DAIICTHostel daiict23.18772300000000000072.627283000000000000

--Page 1 of 4--

---- Next -> Last ->>

Comment: @alpesh Those are notices not fatal errors. It's there to help show issues that might cause your code to break, or better suggestions on how to word something, but in this case it's nothing to get worked up about

Comment: i have got answer...watch next answers

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is not set, simply display the first x number of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_GET['pagenum']))
{
  $pagenum = '1';
}
else
{
  $pagenum = intval($_GET['pagenum']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$pagenum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['pagenum'])) {
  $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
```